# Linear independence and subset of element

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S =\{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Is $u_1+u_k$ an element of S?

My argument is no, because all the vectors in S must be linearly independent to each other, and that $u_1+u_k$ is an element in $\operatorname{span}(S)$.
Is this correct?

Comment: This question needs to be elaborated, if $S=\{1,2\}$ then clearly $1+2 \notin S$, but it has nothing to do with linear independence.

Comment: Look at copper.hat's comment.  Does S need to be a linearly independent set?  Please edit your query accordingly.  Assuming so, then the first question you might ask yourself is: must $n$ be greater than 1?

Comment: So u1 + UK doesn't have to be in S right? But it is always in span (S) right?